# Get File Length from header Java Android

Tags: java, android, http

I have Java code I tried many variants but didn't help.
Some hosting are closing file Content length (size of file )so please help me to read file size from header.
Here is the part of my streaming code when so I need to open the list and read  the int value am I right?

```
is = ucon.getInputStream();
fileLength = ucon.getContentLength();
List headersize = ucon.getHeaderFields().get("content-Lenght");
```

Comment: It's actually called `Content-Length`...

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png");
URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
System.out.println(openConnection.getContentLength());
```

According [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29):

> ```
> public int getContentLength()
> ```
>
> Returns the value of the content-length header field.
>
> **Returns:** the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, or -1 if the content length is not known.

The method does the same thing you are trying to do manually. And if not defined you will receive `-1`

Comment: List headersize = ucon.getHeaderFields().get("content-Lenght");

but is there any way to read the file size from header of the file

Comment: two points: 1. the right header is: `Content-Length` starting with a big `C` and ending with `th` and not `ht` ;), 2. what exactly do you mean with: read the file size from header of the file? Because the file itself doesn't have a header containing the size, but the HTTP response for the resource request through the URLConnection yes, and if this is the case you could use the method I commented on the answer that will already access the header `Content-Length` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have spelt `Content-Length` wrong. Use this spelling

Comment: URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
int fileLength = ucon.getContentLength();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);